# change() fires on page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, uikit

Quick background:
I got a project that some developer worked on a couple of years ago and his code is a nightmare, let alone that almost all the software is outdated. The JQuery in the project is still 1.5.2 but I was able to work around that using the non-conflict option of JQuery.

However, I still can't seem to make the change() function work properly - it fires when the page is being loaded. Furthermore, for some strange reason, the On() function doesn't work either.

Here's the code (below the body):

```
jQuery_3_2_1(document).ready(function(){
jQuery_3_2_1("input[id^=DepartureDay]").on('change',alert('dd'));
```

And here's the non-conflict function (if it's relevant):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_3_2_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

I don't know if it's relevant, but wired thing about the code is that the previous programmer decided load all the HTML using JS strings. Another thing that I should note is that I'm trying to detect a change in the value of a uikit datepicker.

Thank you for your help!

I add a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vzeuhohm/1/#&togetherjs=Sietj3k5oM
**Another edit:**
https://jsfiddle.net/vzeuhohm/2/
Another edit:
I attach the full code in the hope that someone would be able to understand what is wrong with it -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="uikit.docs.min.css" type="text/css">
<script language="javascript" src="https://getuikit.com/v2/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://getuikit.com/v2/src/js/components/datepicker.js"></script>

<link href="example160/css/jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="example160/js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="example160/js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_3_2_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery_3_2_1(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery_3_2_1("[id^=DepartureDay]").ready(function(){
        jQuery_3_2_1("[id^=DepartureDay]").on('input',function(e){
            alert('ff');
        });
    });
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
             <input type="text" name="DepartureDay1" id="DepartureDay1" data-uk-datepicker="{format:'DD.MM.YYYY'}" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
        </form>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery_3_2_1("input[id^=DepartureDay]").on('change',function(){alert('dd');});

Comment: Now it doesn't work at all..

Comment: @EliRotenberg you need to share more detail so we can help, can you share fiddle or snippet ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is highly problematic, for two reasons: the code itself is so badly written that it simply doesn't allow for an easy disentanglement and I don't own the project so I can't release the code freely.

I will understand if it turns out that so little information doesn't allow people to be able to help.

Comment: @DhavalPankhaniya I add a fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/vzeuhohm/1/#&togetherjs=Sietj3k5oM

Comment: @EliRotenberg could you please check and let me know weather it is working for you or not

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$(document).ready()`, try using

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $("input[id^=DepartureDay]").on('change',alert('dd');
});
```

**EDIT**

```
var jQuery_3_2_1 = $.noConflict(true);
jQuery_3_2_1(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery_3_2_1('[id^=DepartureDay]').on('input', function(){alert('dd');});
});
```

Instead of `.on('change'...`, use `.on('input'...)`.

You also have to say `function(){alert('dd');}` instead of just `alert('dd')`.

Comment: Didn't work. I'm attaching a beta non-functional version of the code :
https://jsfiddle.net/vzeuhohm/1/#&togetherjs=Sietj3k5oM

Comment: Try the new edit and see if that works, you also have to add the jQuery Library on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the *result* of calling `alert('dd')` as the change handler.

You probably want to wrap the alert in a function, and pass that function as the handler instead:

```
jQuery_3_2_1("input[id^=DepartureDay]").on("change", function() {
  alert("dd");
});
```

Comment: Too may errors in that jsfiddle: you haven't wrapped `function() { ... }` around your ready callback.  You called `ready()` instead of `ready(function() { ... })`, and you haven't imported jQuery under the name you're using.

Answer (score 0):

try following code

> textbox change event doesn't fire until textbox loses focus.

that's why i am posting both example

```js
jQuery_3_2_1(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery_3_2_1("input[id^='DepartureDay']").on("change", function() {
      alert("your change event is working !!!");
    });      
});
jQuery_3_2_1("input[id^='DepartureDay2']").on('change keyup paste', function() {
    console.log('your change/keyup event is working !!!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_3_2_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="DepartureDay" id="DepartureDay" />
    <input type="text" name="DepartureDay2" id="DepartureDay2" />
</form>
```